# PHP mail multipart/mixed cut off Outlook 2010

Tags: php, email, outlook

I am developing a mailing system with use of PHP. I am very close to completion, as it all works well except for Outlook (I'm currently testing in Outlook 2010, on Windows 7).

The e-mail is `multipart/mixed`; it contains a `multipart/alternative` set of HTML and plain-text alternatives and optionally attachments. It all gets sent properly, and if I check the original headers in Gmail, it looks like it should look. However, if I check the original headers at Outlook, it cuts off anything after the `multipart/mixed`-declaration. I've included the headers here. I simplified them; stripping the actual plain text, html, emailaddresses, and simplifying the boundaries. The headers that Gmail shows me, look somewhat like this:

```
(... information about receiving by the server ...)
To: "Hidden recipients" <noreply@domain.com>
Subject: Een BCC
From: "My Name"<my@email.com>
Reply-To: my@email.com
Date: Sun, 19 Jul 2015 14:16:31 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="PHP-mixed"

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
--PHP-mixed
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt"
--PHP-alt
Content-type:text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
... here's the plain text alternative
--PHP-alt
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
... here's the html-formatted text
--PHP-alt--
--PHP-mixed--
```

The headers that Outlook shows me, look somewhat like this:

```
(... information about receiving by the server ...)
To: "Hidden recipients" <noreply@domain.com>
Subject: Een BCC
From: "My Name"<my@email.com>
Reply-To: my@email.com
Date: Sun, 19 Jul 2015 14:16:31 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="PHP-mixed"
```

My question is, how does this happen, and how can I solve this problem? Why does Gmail play along well, whereas Outlook doesn't?

Comment: That's not a realistic example. But looks like you're assembling the MIME sections manually. Consider something proven, like SwiftMailer/PHPMailer, instead of handicrafting something that's hard to fix.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently giving PHPMailer a try. Seems easy to implement, even though I am on a shared server host. Now that I've sent a simple multipart/alternative email, I see that "viewing the complete headers" in outlook actually  is deliberately cutting off the message body from the headers!  At least it works better. I'll fill in an answer to my own question when I get it done! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference to people stumbling upon an issue similar to mine, I post this answer. As many other SO questions related to sending mails through PHP state, it is advisable to use other libraries. Many libraries exist, it is up to you to choose between these libraries which you are going to implement.

As Mario stated in the comments of this question, it is very recommendable to use a library for sending more advanced emails! For me, composing the correct headers has been a total pain, and these libraries are easy-to-use, and you'll probably end up with better results than with building your own "mail library".

- [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
- [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) (I chose this one for my application)
- Possibly some others.. Just query Google for what you need.

I experienced PHPMailer as easy to implement; just copying the code to my directory worked! I'm not sure about SwiftMailer, but I guess it works similar.

Bottomline: don't be stubborn, use libraries! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Outlook shows what it is supposed to show: the MIME **headers**. It does not show the whole MIME message. Is the message itself displayed correctly by Outlook?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Nope, the message is not displayed at all; it appears blank on the screen. I did not use a library for sending emails, but currently I am trying PHPMailer, and it seems to work out (but I have yet to implement it in the system I am making).